# Please identify this early film that mentions black holes

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

Scifi film probably 70's.

**Description:**

A spaceship exploring  right near the end, the crew venture near a black hole which you never "see", but they know what it is because they send out a beam of light that is very obviously bent into a circular arc.
The film was in color and probably from the US. I suppose it was from the 70's, since black holes were not mentioned much in popular medias until this time.

Comment: you should accept an answer for future reference

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure it's "Into Infinity" a 1975 After School Special. I also remember watching it as a child.

Here's the link to the IMDb http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074690/

This link has better images: http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/31711-into-infinity

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the DVD was only made available to members of "Fanderson" (the Gerry Anderson fan club), and it's no longer listed on their dvd page at http://www.fanderson.org.uk/fansales/fansale.html#Videos  However, I did find that the page at http://fanderson.org.uk/gerryandersonnews/2014/02/the-day-after-tomorrow-dvd-trailer/ has a youtube trailer for the DVD: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T6J_dhw6L8

Comment: If you go to just before 1:00 in that youtube video and hit play, you'll see a scene with what looks like a green laser following a curved path, maybe that's the scene WillS was remembering?

Answer (score 3):

I have a vague memory a movie with a scene like that being shown in school for some reason.  I think it was called "**E=mc<sup>2</sup>**", but I have not been able to find it online.  It was a family on a space exploration mission.

I remember a girl saying "There's a blue planet up ahead," and her brother replying that it just looks blue because of the Doppler effect, and when they pass it the planet will appear to turn red.  This happens, and the girl calls him a know-it-all.

I remember also that as they're trying unsuccessfully to escape the black hole's gravitational field, they detect that the black hole is rotating, and that theoretically a rotating black hole is a gateway to another universe.  They end up going through, and the stars in the other universe look they were filmed with a different lens to give them points.

EDIT: Bobby Newmark has it right.  I thought it was called "**E=mc<sup>2</sup>**" because according to the [Wikipedia page on Into Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_(TV_special)),

> In his script, Byrne proposed that E=mc<sup>2</sup>, the Einsteinian
>   formula that relates mass to energy, should appear on-screen at
>   intervals.

Comment: Happy to help out!  Don't forget to mark Bobby Newmark's answer as "accepted".